# JMeter TCP Sampler doesn't recognize end of stream

Tags: sockets, tcp, jmeter

I'm trying to run a simple test with TCP Sampler

When using default TCPClient class, after the response timeout time passes, I receive a correct response from the server, and then Error 500 in sampler results:

> Response code: 500 Response message:
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException:

It seems like that JMeter does not recognize end of message characters (the server sends **\r\n**).

How can I configure JMeter to see the EOM?

---

I tried to use BinaryTCPClientImpl, and set **tcp.BinaryTCPClient.eomByte = 13** in **Jmeter.properties**, but binaryTCPClient expects HEX data, while I send human readable string, and it still ignores the eomByte...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

Those server did not sent \r\n in several cases. 
Everything started working after the server was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same behaviour and examined the offered responses (sending \r\n at the end of the message in the server side \ setting the *eol byte value* option in the gui) but it didn't work for me.

**My solution:** Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363303/sending-eol-byte-for-request-in-tcp-sampler) I found that \0 is the eol character Jmeter expects in TCP sampler. when my server terminates the messages with \0 - the message is receieved in Jmeter.

**Some more references:** [Jmeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) (TCPClientImpl chapter - that's where the [tcp.eolByte](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/AbstractTCPClient.html#eolByte) is discussed).

**Some option:** if the size of the messages is constant, one can examine LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245970/jmeter-tcp-sampler-doesnt-recognize-end-of-stream)).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone give me a solution for this error. Why I m getting 500 response code why jmeter throwing  the read exception and what is the solution for this error if I already received my success response.

Answer (score -2):

TCP Sampler will not return until EOF is received.
Set your own EOF byte value at TCP Sampler.
The server sends a stream at the end of EOF byte value.