# Sending EOL byte for request in TCP Sampler

Tags: java, sockets, jmeter, apache-mina

So, I am having TCP socket server which defines text based client server communication. I want to measure performance of this service using jmeter's TCP Sampler but the problem is that I cannot find a way to send EOL byte for every request. From what I see the server defines "\0" as line delimiter. From what I understand the field 'End of line(EOL) byte value' is for parsing server response and its value is not considered when request is being made.

Using the following code I am able to connect to my server and line delimiter is properly parsed:

```
NioSocketConnector connector = new NioSocketConnector();

TextLineCodecFactory customTextLineCodecFactory = new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
    LineDelimiter.NUL, LineDelimiter.NUL);

connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(customTextLineCodecFactory));
connector.setHandler(this);
IoSession session;

for (;;) {
    try {
        ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new 
        InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8090));
        future.awaitUninterruptibly();
        session = future.getSession();
        break;
    } catch (RuntimeIoException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

// wait until the summation is done
session.write("sth");
session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
connector.dispose();
```

I am using **Apache Mina** library for socket communication.

With TCP Sampler I get connected to my server, but line delimiter is not sent and the server does not know where the packet ends.

My question is: How do I send end of line byte using default TCPClientImpl of TCP Sampler?

Answer (score 0):

In TCP Sampler set the property:

```
tcp.eolByte=0
```

or if in Java code:

```
tcpClient.setEolByte(0);
```

... which will force your string EOLs to be **NULL Strings**

Below you can see EOL byte value on the right of the screen shoot.

[image: The EOL is on the right]

Comment: This is equivalent to 'End of line(EOL) byte value', right ? As I mentioned this seems not to work. In Wireshark I see that there is no ending byte attached.  In contrast, when triggering request with the java code showed in the question the ending byte is attached to data body.

Comment: have you set EOL byte on the `TCPClientImpl` or any other class which implements `TCPClient` interface ?

Comment: As I haven't set TCPClient classname in JMeter GUI I think it falls back on TCPClientImpl by default. BTW I am using JMeter 4.0